# Need the add the date by 1 year in postgreSQL using golang

Tags: postgresql, go, orm, beego

I am using golang and postgreSQL version 9.5.5 in my application. I am using `github.com/lib/pq` as my database driver to connect to the database. One of my fields(resetdate) have the type date. I would like to add the resetdate by 1 year. So I used the following code:

**Note**:I m using beego as my framework and use orm to compute my
 queries.

```
_, err := o.Raw("UPDATE resetdate=resetdate + interval  '1 year'  WHERE resetdate>=?","2016-12-12").Exec()
```

When I execute this I'm getting the following error:

> "pq: syntax error at or near \"=\""

Appreciate any help.Thanks

Comment: You're missing the table name and `SET` keyword after `UPDATE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that problem can be solved including the "SET" in your update statement 
`_, err := o.Raw("UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET resetdate=resetdate + interval '1 year'  WHERE resetdate>=?","2016-12-12").Exec()`

Reference: [Postgres UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html)

Comment: Thanks very much...Solved